# An application of the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

How would one find the residue of the function around an arbitrary point $z_0$ and using the branch cut $z\in(0,2\pi]$

$$R(z) = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{z+a}+\ln(z+b))^n}$$

Where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n$ is an integer? I tried doing a Laurent series expansion in the denominator but I'm not sure how to handle it being raised to the $n$th power and write that as the sum of reciprocal terms .

Comment: Perhaps @sos440 would know?

Comment: or even @RonGordon?